# 1x11 speed road bike conversion

Tags: chain

I  am converting my 52x42 12 speed to 1x11 speed.

I am wanting to put a 46t chainring on the crank.

My question is will the 11speed chain run on this chainring which is 3/32" thick.

Comment: Should be fine, the front chainring will not care about the exterior width of the chain.  You may need to keep the FD mech as a chain guide.

Comment: What type of chain rings do you have?

Comment: Wait, 52x42 12 speed? I'm guessing you're not running a 2x6 setup...

Comment: @Batman is right - watch out: if you were really using a 6s rear hub, you won't be able to fit a 11s cassette onto this hub, you'd need a new rear hub.

Comment: @ColinHorsfall - If you're running 2x6, note that you need a different rear wheel to fit a 11 speed cassette since a 6 speed wheel will be a freewheel wheel, and you'll need to likely respace the rear dropouts.  And I'm guessing you're running flat bars, cause a deore shifter won't fit on drop bars. Have you thought the compatibility of everything else other than the chain through?

Comment: Thanks lads.Yes i have a obtained a modern pair of wheels. Should be up and running soon.i do have drop bars so i am still trying to think the shifter problem through.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 11-speed chains are still 3/32" chains, which means the inside width of the inner link is 3/32".

However, consider that we're now living in the age of narrow-wide rings. They make one-by setups run way better.

Comment: The variation in tooth size will mean a new chain, new chainrings at least.  Does it require a new cassette too?

Comment: @Criggie It would work with whatever chain and cassette they were already planning on using for their new 1x11 drivetrain. The proposal is simply to use a narrow-wide ring rather than one for singlespeed/multi-ring use because they give much better chain retention. Ad copy for them says "1x11" all over so I assumed that using one wasn't already the plan.

Comment: The present setup is 2x6. My new shimano 11/42 cassette 11spd arrived yesterday complete with 11spd chain, deore xt derailleur, deore rapid fire shift lever and cables. I now need to find a 46t narrow wide chainring to complete my roadbike 1x11 setup. I have found a 3/32" fixie chainring on the net but i agree a narrow wide would be better. Any ideas where i could order one from.

Comment: @ColinHorsfall I looked and saw only Garbaruk making 46x130, which is a little surprising but at least it exists. 44t is very common.

Comment: Nathan i checked Garbaruk but they only have up to 44. I have bought a single speed Blackspire 3/32". Be here doon. Hope that works ok.